# Nginx welcome message displaying instead of Wordpress index.php

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have a site made by wordpress. It was working properly but today I see "Welcome to nginx!" message instead of my site first page and show "404 Not Found" instead of other pages. I dont know what is nginx and dont know so much wordpress. how can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MySky

nginx, (pronounced "engine X" by the way ) when installed will automatically look for an index.html file in your root folder and display this.

Nginx will create a page called index.html when it is installed, and this is the page that you are seeing. Check the folder where your wordpress installation is contained and:

1. If there is an *index.html* - rename it to something else, i.e *index.html.old*
2. When you ran the wordpress installer, it created a file named *index.php* - this would have been called if there was no conflicting *index.html*

Once you complete the above steps, go to the homepage of your wordpress site and it will display the contents correctly.